# parent directive erasing child ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning angularjs through the process of taking an existing site that was built primarily with JQuery and trying to "angularize" it.  I am having trouble reproducing the same functionality in angular.

Please see the following plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/n4cbcRviuzNsieVvr4Im?p=preview

I have a ul element with an angularjs directive called "scroller" as seen below.

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu-list scroller" scroller style="height: 250px">
            <li data-ng-repeat="n in notifications">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-plus"></i></span>
                    {{n.summary}}
                <span class="time">{{n.time}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The scroller directive looks like this:

```
.directive('scroller', function () {
  return {
      priority: 0,
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
          done: '&',
          progress: '&'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          $('.scroller').each(function () {
              var height;
              if ($(this).attr("data-height")) {
                  height = $(this).attr("data-height");
              } else {
                  height = $(this).css('height');
              }
              $(this).slimScroll({
                  size: '7px',
                  color: '#a1b2bd',
                  height: height,
                  disableFadeOut: true
              });
          });


      }
  };
```

What i want to happen is that the ng-repeat executes on the notifications array in the controller, producing a collection of li elements that exceed 250px therefore a slimscrollbar would be added.  What actually happens is the result of the ng-repeat is not included in the final DOM. I believe the call in the parent scroller directive of $(this).slimScroll() is called **after** the ng-repeat executes and replaces the DOM.  If i remove the scroller attribute, the li elements show up.

I am sure there is a strategy for this and am hoping the community can educate me on a better approach or alternate approach.  thoughts?  again the plunker is here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/n4cbcRviuzNsieVvr4Im?p=preview

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is actually your directive scope. You are using an explicit object as the scope, which means you are isolating the scope, which means the directive scope isn't inheriting from its parent anymore. So notifications from the parent controller is no longer reachable from the directive scope (and therefore any elements inside of its element).

If you remove this from your directive it should work:

```
  scope: {
      done: '&',
      progress: '&'
  }
```

I notice that you aren't using those attributes anyway so it shouldn't break any other functionality.

Look at the API docs http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and look for isolate scope for more details.

An alternative to what you're trying to do would just be something like this

```
scope.$watch(attr.done, function(val) { //do something when the value changes })
```

Since I don't know your use case I can't say what the best solution would be.

Comment: Adam, i followed your advice and removed the scope from the directive but this did not fix the issue.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/q1E7IMzVJ4qc3VCeFRhl?p=preview -- is that not what you wanted? Seems to work to me...

Comment: Adam, my apologies.  Despite making the change, it was not working for me.  I saved the plunker, closed my browser and reloaded it and now it is working.  Appreciate your help!